# Extracting values from CSV list in python

Tags: python, csv

I have importet a list from my CSV file (CHFJPY15.csv)

but i am having truble with extracting the values from the list and structure them.

```
import csv
import operator
sample = open('CHFJPY15.csv', 'r')
csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=', ')
sort = sorted(csv1,key= operator.itemgetter(0=))
for eachline in sort:
     print eachline
```

a part of the list:

```
['2017.07.21', '22:00', '117.602', '117.608', '117.577', '117.596',
'884'] ['2017.07.21', '22:15', '117.594', '117.604', '117.538',
'117.541', '804'] ['2017.07.21', '22:30', '117.541', '117.545',
'117.487', '117.497', '964'] ['2017.07.21', '22:45', '117.497',
'117.515', '117.474', '117.507', '1440'] ['2017.07.21', '23:00',
'117.506', '117.543', '117.498', '117.529', '1385'] ['2017.07.21',
'23:15', '117.528', '117.534', '117.478', '117.512', '718']
['2017.07.21', '23:30', '117.511', '117.530', '117.411', '117.422',
'1426']
```

Comment: can you explain further?  what are you trying to retrieve and from where?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .csv you can use the genfromtxt function. It will return you a numpy array and you can access each position as in a matrix, its very convenient.